# What is the fastest way to do this string patten substitution based on the logical relations in Python?

Tags: python, regex, logical-operators

For example,

```
 1. str1 = 'A>1 and A>=3 and B<2 and B<=3 and B<1 ...', should be substituted to:
    str1 = 'A>=3 and B<1 ...';  

 2. str2=['A=1 and B<=2 ...', 'A=1 and B>2 ...'], should be substituted to:
    str2=['A=1 ...'], where B is skipped
```

A, B can be any length legal python identifiers. There are unknown number of logical operands in both str1 and str2.

The usual regex search approach is quite challenging to solve this problem. Any hack idea?

EDIT:

To make the question simple, let's consider 'and' operation only, and all operands are sorted as a string, namely

```
 'A<x and A<y and A<z' will always appear next to each other
```

Comment: I don't really see how you can solve this with a regex. I'd say you need to parse your strings (this step can be done with a regex, if your format is sufficiently restricted) and run a simple interpreter on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
import re


str1 = "A>1 and A>3 and B<2 and B<3"
comparisions = [s.strip() for s in str1.split("and")]
operands = [re.search(r'(\w+)([<>][=]?)(\w+)',c).groups() for c in comparisions]#

tot={}#total results
for k,g in groupby(operands,lambda x:x[0]):#group by variable1
    for arg in g:#arg is the match with list [var1,compareitem,var2]
        if k not in tot:tot[k] = {}
        if arg[1] in tot[k]:
            print("do the overwrite handling!")
        tot[k][arg[1]] = arg[2]

#sort tot
sortedkeys = sorted(tot, key=lambda x: x[0])

resub_str = " and ".join([comp+"".join([k+tot[comp][k] for k in tot[comp]]) for comp in sortedkeys])
print(resub_str)
```

## Output:

```
do the overwrite handling!
do the overwrite handling!
A>3 and B<3
```

## The Idea:

1. Split the string in an array of conditional statements.
   So that we have `[A>1,A>3,B<2,B<3]` and so on.
2. Search each condition with a pattern, that matches [VARIABLE1][COMPARE_ITEM][VARIABLE2] where `COMPARE_ITEM` is one of `<,>,<=,>=`
3. We now group by `VARIABLE1` and search the results if we already have a condition for `VARIABLE1`. If we have - do the overwriting. If not, just insert it.
4. Sort the array by `VARIABLE1` and join the condition-parts with `" and "`

You may improve the code by not just searching Var1, but searching also for variable2 and create a reference for each variable used.

(So that conditions like `A<B and A< 4` result the same as `B>A and 4>A`).

Comment: Work it out yourself, it shouldn't be that hard. I'll explain what my idea was if you want. You can apply this idea to the second part

Comment: Can you explain your idea above?